# RoR rails new command not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning RoR throgh Michael Hartl's book.On chapter three while creating sample_app through the command rails new sample_app --skip-unit-test I got this after run bundle intstall.

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize': Connection timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:632:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:224:in `connection_for'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:358:in `request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:145:in `fetch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:173:in `fetch_dependency_remote_specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:132:in `fetch_remote_specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:70:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/source.rb:234:in `block in remote_specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `remote_specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/source.rb:165:in `fetch_specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/source.rb:70:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:205:in `block (2 levels) in index'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:202:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:202:in `block in index'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:198:in `index'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `resolve'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:122:in `resolve_remotely!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:48:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:12:in `install'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220:in `install'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/bin/bundle:13:in `<main>'
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler 
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
```

Tried a lot of things like gem update --system and install bundler.Still not working and I have no idea why.Please HELP

```
My system details-

ruby -v
>> ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]

rails -v
>> Rails 3.1.0

gem -v
>> 2.1.8
```

I m working on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Seems like you're having troubles with the network connection (bundler can't phone home).

Comment: try `sudo gem update --system` and relaunch `bundle install`

Comment: Rubygems has problems today. Try again later...

Comment: I checked the OpenSSL certificate it was up to date

Comment: Having this same problem for last 2 days

Comment: After sudo gem update --system I m getting a new error- NoMethodError: private method `open' called for Gem::Package:Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the bundles will fail if the top of
your gemfile is source 'https://rubygems.org' try changing https to http